# SVG filter def not working on IE11

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, svg, cross-browser

I have a `svg` element on my page and have created a definition to contain a filter specifying a drop-shadow effect

The effects work perfectly on Chrome and Firefox but IE11 is not rendering the effects.

```html
<svg class="historicUploadDonuts" width="254.375" height="254.375" filter="url(&quot;#ieDropShadow0&quot;)">
  <defs>
    <filter id="ieDropShadow0" height="130%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3" result="blur"></feGaussianBlur>
      <feOffset in="blur" result="offsetBlur" dx="3" dy="3"></feOffset>
      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode></feMergeNode>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g class="slices" transform="translate(117.1875,117.1875)">
    <g class="labelName">
      <circle class="cleanCircle" fill="none" r="58.59375"></circle>
      <text class="cleanText" fill="#000" style="font-size: 11.7188px; text-anchor: middle;" font-weight="bold"></text>
    </g>
    <path class="chart-no-data" stroke="0" d="M5.740531871003218e-15,-93.75A93.75,93.75,0,0,1,93.75,0L58.59375,0A58.59375,58.59375,0,0,0,3.5878324193770114e-15,-58.59375Z"></path>
    <path class="chart-no-data" stroke="0" d="M93.75,0A93.75,93.75,0,0,1,5.740531871003218e-15,93.75L3.5878324193770114e-15,58.59375A58.59375,58.59375,0,0,0,58.59375,0Z"></path>
    <path class="chart-no-data" stroke="0" d="M5.740531871003218e-15,93.75A93.75,93.75,0,0,1,-93.75,1.1481063742006436e-14L-58.59375,7.175664838754023e-15A58.59375,58.59375,0,0,0,3.5878324193770114e-15,58.59375Z"></path>
    <path class="chart-no-data" stroke="0" d="M-93.75,1.1481063742006436e-14A93.75,93.75,0,0,1,-1.7221595613009652e-14,-93.75L-1.0763497258131033e-14,-58.59375A58.59375,58.59375,0,0,0,-58.59375,7.175664838754023e-15Z"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

I followed the example here - http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/filters/arrow-with-dropshadow.svg - but cannot get the effects to work on IE11

The example which works uses a polygon - is there a reason why the svg I am using is NOT picking up the filter `ieDropShadow0` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the filter on the outermost `g.slices` element. Leave off the inner quotes.

```html
<svg class="historicUploadDonuts" width="254.375" height="254.375">
  <defs>
    <filter id="ieDropShadow0" height="130%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3" result="blur"></feGaussianBlur>
      <feOffset in="blur" result="offsetBlur" dx="3" dy="3"></feOffset>
      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode></feMergeNode>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g class="slices" filter="url(#ieDropShadow0)" transform="translate(117.1875,117.1875)">
    <g class="labelName">
      <circle class="cleanCircle" fill="none" r="58.59375"></circle>
      <text class="cleanText" fill="#000" style="font-size: 11.7188px; text-anchor: middle;" font-weight="bold"></text>
    </g>
    <path class="chart-no-data" stroke="0" d="M5.740531871003218e-15,-93.75A93.75,93.75,0,0,1,93.75,0L58.59375,0A58.59375,58.59375,0,0,0,3.5878324193770114e-15,-58.59375Z"></path>
    <path class="chart-no-data" stroke="0" d="M93.75,0A93.75,93.75,0,0,1,5.740531871003218e-15,93.75L3.5878324193770114e-15,58.59375A58.59375,58.59375,0,0,0,58.59375,0Z"></path>
    <path class="chart-no-data" stroke="0" d="M5.740531871003218e-15,93.75A93.75,93.75,0,0,1,-93.75,1.1481063742006436e-14L-58.59375,7.175664838754023e-15A58.59375,58.59375,0,0,0,3.5878324193770114e-15,58.59375Z"></path>
    <path class="chart-no-data" stroke="0" d="M-93.75,1.1481063742006436e-14A93.75,93.75,0,0,1,-1.7221595613009652e-14,-93.75L-1.0763497258131033e-14,-58.59375A58.59375,58.59375,0,0,0,-58.59375,7.175664838754023e-15Z"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```